# How to remove an instance of object from a list in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in python and I was wondering how I can remove an instance of an object from a list ? 
Here's a part of my code in which I get an error: "list.remove(x): x not in list".

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.minDistance = float("inf")
        self.previousVertex = None
        self.edges = []

    def computePath(self, sourceId):
        for i in self.vertexes:
            if i.id == sourceId:
                startVertex = i
                startVertex.minDistance=0
                break
            else:
                continue
        unvisited = []
        for vertex in self.vertexes:
            unvisited.append(vertex)
        while len(unvisited)!=0:
            self.visited.append(startVertex)
            unvisited.remove(startVertex)
```

Comment: You keep trying to remove `startVertex` over and over in the loop.

Comment: Also `pop()` is a good function to remove things from list too as it does it in place.

Comment: @MooingRawr so does `.remove`

Comment: @user2357112 I prevent it from doing so later in the code, I just didnt want to post the whole code cause it would be too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.remove()` will remove the first item from the list where that item is equal to whatever you wanted to remove.

In other words, the algorithm is to do this:

```
def remove(self, item_to_remove):
    for index, item in enumerate(self):
        if item == item_to_remove:
            del self[index]
            return
    raise ValueError('list.remove(x): x not in list')
```

The trick then is to make the `==` equality test pass. This is done with the [`__eq__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__). The *default* implementation is to only return `True` when the two items are *one and the same object*, so `item is item_to_remove` is true.

You can create a custom method for your `Vertex` class:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Vertex):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.id == other.id  # refine as needed
```

You need to decide when two `Vertex` instances are equal.